# What CSS syntax do I need to use to access the Label of a TitledPane in JavaFX?

Tags: java, css, syntax, javafx, stylesheet

I don't really know a lot about CSS in the context of JavaFX.
I'm trying to access the Labels of some TitledPanes so I can put a simple image next to the Label but I can't figure out what the proper syntax is to do so.

I've tried:

```
.TitledPane > .title > .text { //TitledPane is the CSS class I assign to my Title Panes.
    /*CSS Code Here*/
}
```

That didn't work.

```
.TitledPane > .title { } //This only affects the background, I would like the graphic to be side-by-side with the actual text.

.TitlePane LabeledText { } //This worked with Buttons so I thought it might work with TitledPane. I was wrong.
```

What do I need to use to access the Label to be able to style it with CSS?

Comment: This has nothing to do with HTML. This is JavaFX. JavaFX controls can use CSS stylesheets to dictate their style.

Comment: Do you need css for this? Why not just do `myTitledPane.setGraphic(...)` in the Java code (or the equivalent in FXML)?

Comment: Yeah I know that's an option but if it's possible to do in CSS I'd prefer that as to keep the Java code relatively concise. That's kind of a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CSS documentation for `TitledPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#titledpane) appears to be wrong: the `text` class in the title actual resolves to a `Text` object, not a `Label`, as stated. Of course, `Text` does not support an `-fx-graphic` css property.

Fortunately, since `TitledPane` extends `Labeled`, you can just use the property defined in `Labeled` directly:

```
.TitledPane {
  -fx-graphic: url(path/to/image/file) ;
}
```